# delete a character from a string by using pointers and not the index (in c)

Tags: c, pointers

I need a function that deletes a character in a string at an index without brackets[], instead i have to use pointers. I am not allowed to use memmove or another function. This is what I have so far:

```c
void stringDeleteChar(char *s, int index){
    int i = 0;
    char *hold = NULL;

    if (index > strlen(s) || index < 0){
        s = '\0';
    }
    else{
        s += index;
        hold = s+1;
        while (i < strlen(s)){
            *s = *hold;
            s++;
            hold++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `s = '\0'` has no effect ignored it and get out of the function. However, `index < 0` is wrong, since you might want to remove the first element of the array as well:

```
void stringDeleteChar(char *s, int index){    
    if (index <= strlen(s) && index >= 0){
       for (char* str_pointer = s + index; *str_pointer != '\0'; str_pointer++)
            *str_pointer = *(str_pointer + 1);
    }
}
```

You start with the pointer (*i.e.,* str_pointer) pointing to the position of the element to be removed (*i.e.,* `char* str_pointer= s + index`). Then the rest is just shifting to the left by one all the remaining elements of the array. Or in another words `array[i] = array[i+1]` until `'\0'` is reach.

When you compare the version with pointers against the one (explicitly) without them:

```
for (int i = index; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    s[i] = s[i+1];
```

You can see that `s[i]` is equivalent to `*str_pointer`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to take care of the `while` loop, the `s` changes inside loop so , it will not give you correct output, so just check your `hold` as any data until `\0`.

```
  else{
        s += index+1;
        hold = s+1;
        putchar(*s);putchar(*hold);
        while (*hold){
            *s = *hold;
            s++;
            hold++;
            i++;
        }
        *s = *hold;
    }
```